# Ionic push notification is not working if app is open

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am able to send push form apps.ionic.io and from postman when app is on background or screen is locked but not able to send notification when app is open.
My code is as 
 in run

```
    var io = Ionic.io();
            var push = new Ionic.Push({
               "onNotification": function(notification) {
            alert('Received push notification!');
          },
           "pluginConfig": {
                    "android": {
                        "icon": "ic_stat_icon"
                    }
                },
          "debug": true
        });
 push.register(function(token) {
      console.log("registered");
      console.log("Device token:",token.token);
    });
```

and in controller

```
 $ionicPush.register( {
    canShowconsole.log: true, //Can pushes show an console.log on your screen?
    canShowAlert: true, //Can pushes show an alert on your screen?
    canSetBadge: true, //Can pushes update app icon badges?
    canPlaySound: true, //Can notifications play a sound?
    canRunActionsOnWake: true, //Can run actions outside the app,
    onNotification: function(notification) {
       console.log(notification);
     // Handle new push notifications here
     alert('Received push notification!');
     return true;
   }
        }).then(function(t) {
    return $ionicPush.saveToken(t);
  }).then(function(t) {
    console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
  });
```

Comment: I'm also having same issue, did you find any solution. If you find anything please share.

Comment: No luck ,I am currently not working on that .when i will work then let you know,

Comment: also facing same issue. @AnujGupta you find something?

Comment: @VinothKumar did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing in your app.js or controller file.

```
$rootScope.$on('cloud:push:notification', function(event, data) {
      var msg = data.message;
      console.log(msg);
      // alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);

      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: msg.title,
            template: msg.text.toString()
        });

    });
```

Comment: I checked that GCM in google app,Is this working ? I found FCM there ,

Comment: Where to add this code in Ionic project?